# Spring ConflictingBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, javabeans

I have ProjectA defining a `MyService` class.
ProjectA contains multiple concrete services, for example: `SomeService`.

Now I have ProjectB, which is a spring boot project, having ProjectA as dependency.
ProjectB may add some functions to `SomeService` by defining its own `public class SomeService extends project.a.SomeService {...}`. The beans are scanned via `@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")`.

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans ...>
<context:component-scan base-package="project">
    <context:include-filter type="assignable"
        expression="project.a.MyService" />
</context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Main problem is: This leads to `ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:`

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'someService' for bean class
[project.a.SomeService] conflicts with existing, 
non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [project.b.SomeService]
```

Although the exception is really clear, I have no idea how to solve it. 
 After my research I'm relativley sure `setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(true)` should solve my problem. Maybe I just do it at the wrong time, but it never helped (also I think true is the default value).

**My attempt:**
I tried to avoid all scanning and register my beans by myself as well:

```
GenericApplicationContext ctx = (GenericApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(ProjectBApplication.class, args); 
ctx.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("someService", new project.b.SomeService());
...
```

I can filter `MyService`s specifically this way but now I'm running in autowiring problems using `SomeService` in other (following!) beans.
Maybe I'm just registering the someService bean wrong?

I've already read about BeanPostProcessors, but I did not get how they could help me and where to use them correctly.

 Keep in mind: any solution will fit, no matter if filtering MyService's in code, in xml, just tell spring to overwrite beans with more specific ones or what ever.

Comment: **solved**: I'll post a detailed solution tomorrow, ofc feel free to find and post your own solution

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I just registered the bean wrong. Using

```
GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
beanDefinition.setBeanClass(service);
context.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
```

solved the autowireing problem and at the moment every thing works fine.